# Unable to share files between 2 computers

Tags: wireless-networking

PC1:

- IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.2
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1

PC2:

- IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.4
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1

Firewalls have been disabled. They cannot ping each other and with `arp -a` they do not see each other other.

Comment: More details would help. OS? Version? PC models?

Comment: Windows 10 on both OS, PC models are HP.

Comment: Many routers have an "isolation mode", which prevents devices on a network from communicating with each other. See if your router has that option and disable it.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about that.